# how to click on a fc-timegrid slot ?cypress-automation

Tags: automated-tests, fullcalendar, cypress, fullcalendar-5

I am learning cypress and automating a web application. The web application has grids/tables, the rows are timeslots and the columns are activities like "Sauna", "Spinning", "Yoga" etc. The rows are 10am, 11am etc So if you want to book a Spinning class at 11am, you would click on the intersection of that row and column.I have looked through and tried out solutions given about web tables, I have posted what I have tried towards the end

here is the html:

```
<div class="fc-timegrid fc-resourceTimeGridDay-view fc-view"><table class="fc-scrollgrid  fc-scrollgrid-liquid"><thead><tr class="fc-scrollgrid-section fc-scrollgrid-section-header "><td><div class="fc-scroller-harness"><div class="fc-scroller" style="overflow: hidden scroll;"><table class="fc-col-header " style="width: 1316px;"><colgroup><col style="width: 55px;"></colgroup><tbody><tr><th class="fc-timegrid-axis"><div class="fc-timegrid-axis-frame"></div></th><th class="fc-col-header-cell fc-resource" colspan="1" data-resource-id="QXBwb2ludG1lbnRTbG90OjMwMDE=" data-date="2023-05-11"><div class="fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner"><span class="fc-col-header-cell-cushion ">Sauna</span></div></th><th class="fc-col-header-cell fc-resource" colspan="1" data-resource-id="QXBwb2ludG1lbnRTbG90OjMwMDI=" data-date="2023-05-11"><div class="fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner"><span class="fc-col-header-cell-cushion ">Spinning</span></div>
```

```
<tbody><tr class="fc-scrollgrid-section fc-scrollgrid-section-body  fc-scrollgrid-section-liquid"><td><div class="fc-scroller-harness fc-scroller-harness-liquid"><div class="fc-scroller fc-scroller-liquid-absolute" style="overflow: hidden scroll;"><div class="fc-timegrid-body" style="width: 1316px;"><div class="fc-timegrid-slots"><table class="" style="width: 1316px;"><colgroup><col style="width: 55px;"></colgroup><tbody><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="10:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">10am</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="10:00:00"></td></tr>
```

I read several tutorials online about testing web tables, and tried out this but cypress cannot find the element.
  `cy.get('.fc-scrollgrid.fc-scrollgrid-liquid>tbody>tr:nth-child(4)>td:nth-child(4)').click();` (clicking 4rth row and 4rth column.
How can I go about clicking on the intersection of the row and the column so that I  can book a class?

Answer (score 5):

Grid rows are the `<tr>` element, columns (within row) are `<td>` elements.

So 4th row is `.find('tr').eq(3)` since indexes are zero-based, and similarly 4th column is `.find('td').eq(3)`.

The table I suppose is identified by class (but it would be better to have an id)

```js
cy.get('table.fc-scrollgrid tbody')
  .find('tr').eq(3)
  .find('td').eq(3)
  .click()
```

Now what? What are you testing? You need to devise an assertion that results from the action.

Comment: Thankyou @H.Bouvy it didn't work though...so for tr. eq(3), it selects a entire row, which is expected. For td.eq(3) cypress says, "Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: 3, but never found it. Queried from:
              > cy.get(table.fc-scrollgrid tbody).find(tr).eq(3).find(td)"

Comment: You said ***clicking 4rth row and 4rth column*** - that's what this code does.

Comment: yes, I know that the code is correct for what I asked. But it is not working in this case. The class booking page is a full-calendar-timegrid.